# Python DLL load failed No module Named Error

Tags: python, pyqt5

I want to write a project with python pyqt5. I get an error like this. This error comes out when you want to include the qtwidgets module inside the Pyqt5 library into the project.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: Belirtilen modül bulunamadı.
```

Image link: https://i.hizliresim.com/BaAzE9.png

Comment: You should add full stack trace if its available.

Comment: First off your link gives me "403 Forbidden", second please don't post code or error as images (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) third, please format your text properly next time.